# Handling an npm project as a maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, npm

I'm working on a java project that wants to create regulated security tokens. We'd ideally want to use [Tokeny's TREX](https://github.com/TokenySolutions/T-REX) as the basis for our implementation/extension. The TREX project uses `npm`  for building and dependencies, it downloads them when running `npm install`. The project mainly consists of `.sol` (Solidity) files, and accessing those in my maven project is my goal here.

I have managed to download the repo into maven project using `com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin:download-maven-plugin` with the following config:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-jbpm</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wget</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <url>https://github.com/TokenySolutions/T-REX/archive/refs/heads/main.zip</url>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/TREX</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However this isn't the perfect solution I feel. First of all, getting the .zip url from the github page is a bit of a hack I suspect, as cloning the repo would be the obvious path here. Also I really only need the `contracts` folder from this repo, what's my best option for deleting everything else and only leaving the `contracts` folder and related dependencies?

Additionally, how different would this process be with Jenkins CD that deploys into a Docker image?

Comment: Have you considered using npm to retrieve trex dependency? This is could be done using frontend-maven-plugin which takes care of installing a local version of node+npm so nothing to install on your dev PC or on your Jenkins server. https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Comment: That sounds good. This plugin just installs node+npm and I have to handle the dependency retrieving with another step, right? I know very little about npm, could you point me to a good guide on how I'd achieve that step?

Comment: You must add a package.json to your project to reference a version of trex. If you want an example of a project, see an app generated by JHipster: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

Comment: you might want to have a look at webjars: https://www.webjars.org/

Comment: @GaëlMarziou your comment ended up solving my problem, please consider posting it as an answer to have this question closed

Comment: András you should rather post the solution yourself, it'll be more helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using `frontend-maven-plugin` as mentioned by @GaëlMarziou, here's my code for that:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm for trex</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/node_modules/@tokenysolutions/t-rex</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>trex npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/node_modules/@tokenysolutions/t-rex</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v16.14.0</nodeVersion>
        <npmVersion>8.3.1</npmVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

A couple of things to note: the `npm` goal of the plugin calls `npm install`, the actual command is usually set in configuration, and that is probably more readable too. Secondly, depending on what particular `npm` library you're using, including its dependencies in your `package.json` is a way to avoid having to perform this double install.